# Get Google User data with Keycloak identity provider

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, keycloak

I have succesfully set up Google as Identity Provider in Keycloak, following the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.0/server_admin/index.html#google), and I'm now able to login to my application using keycloak.

Is there a way to get the user data from the google account that is logged in. In my application I would like to retrieve profile information like in [this example](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/) and then add it later to my mappers so I could see it in my Access Token(Adding attributes in my access token is not an issue, that works fine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a request against the userinfo endpoint

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?Access_token=XXX

It should work but you may have to add a `profile` scope to your request i cant remember.